# Deleting a Record in a Form by C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to write a code with Stored Procedure in C# that when the record is found and when clicking on delete button, the record will be deleted.

I had put this Code in *SellerDelete* Form:

```
Model.DB_EstateTBEntities Obj_DB = new Model.DB_EstateTBEntities();
int GridVWID;

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delete Button:
    Obj_DB.Sp_DelByIDSeller(GridVWID);
    int Cnt3 = Obj_DB.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show(" You are Deleting {0} rows!! " + Cnt3);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Obj_DB.Tbl_SellerInfo.ToList();
 }
```

What should I do?

The Error:

> (field) int Frm_SellerDelete.GridVWID
>
> Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'
>
> Show Potential fixes (Ctrl+.)

The *Stored Procedure* query:

```
create procedure Sp_DelByIDSeller 
(@ID int out)
as
begin
delete from Tbl_SellerInfo where ID=@ID
end
```

Comment: Rather than posting a picture of an error, can you paste the text of the exception?

Comment: check the parameter datatype of  Sp_DelByIDSeller

Comment: Post the code of `Obj_DB.Sp_DelByIDSeller` and also the value and datatype of `GridVWID` when the error occurs

Comment: So what datatype is GridVWID? But my guess is the Obj_DB.Sp_DelByIDSeller method is where the issue is happening. Do you know how to debug code? You should set some break points and figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Meanwhile you might want to read this before you continue the habit of using sp_ as a prefix for your procedures. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: In your stored procedure how did you define the "@ID" parameter? I think this "@ID" smells fishy.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you are trying to pass an id "GridVWID" while your Obj_DB is expecting an entity.

please check this article it will help you understand how to delete a record in EF
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B